# Is It Possible to update only a single record(when there are multiple records) in a json file using python?

Tags: python, json, record, updating

Want to update json file partially. Want to update different values different records.

**Example:**

```
[
 {
    "Id": "default",
    "AccountId":1,
 },
{
    "Id": "default",
    "AccountId":2,
}
]
```

Based on some inputs want to update only AccountId in the first record only.Is it possible to do that

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/). For example you are not telling us what you have tried and your question completely lacks any code sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify json data by loading it with the method `json.loads("Your_Json_String")`. Then you can treat it like any other python dict/list.

```
import json

data = """[
    {"Id": "default", "AccountId":1},
    {"Id": "default", "AccountId":2}
    ]"""

json_dict = json.loads(data)

#update the first record
json_dict[0]["AccoundId"] = 10

print(json_dict)
#[{'Id': 'default', 'AccountId': 1, 'AccoundId': 10}, {'Id': 'default', 'AccountId': 2}]

#convert it to json again
json_data = json.dumps(json_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat this as a list. For example if you wanted to change the first one:

```
import json


jsonData = json.load(open("yourfile.json", "r"))

jsonData[0]["AccountId"] = 3

json.dump(jsonData, open("yourfile.json" ,"w"))
```